# XSLT 1.0 transformation removing duplicates using variables

Tags: xslt-1.0

for several reasons, I need to derive a variable in XSLT 1.0 which can be re-used during the transformation, which collects a unique list of duplicate entries.

The input data is generated in the XSLT into a variable "portlist":

```
<plist> 
  <p>12345</p>
  <p>12345</p>
  <p>9876</p>
  <p>12345</p>
<plist>
```

within my XSLT-template, I need a variable "reducedList" to be re-used several times in transformation. How can I generate a new variable "reducedList" in XSLT which looks like

```
<plist> 
  <p>12345</p>
  <p>9876</p>
<plist>
```

I found several examples, but must confess i could not figure out.

My xslt-template looks like

```
<xsl:template match="stage">

   <xsl:variable name="portlist" > <!-- returns a sorted list of all ports -->
       <plist>
          <xsl:for-each select="provider/server/QMGR"><!-- input from XML -->
             <xsl:sort select="."/>
             <p><xsl:value-of select="./@port"/></p>
           </xsl:for-each>
        </plist>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- here i need to derive the new variable reducedList  -->

    <!-- more code using reducedList follows here -->
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:variable name="portlist">
  <plist>
    <p>12345</p>
    <p>12345</p>
    <p>9876</p>
    <p>12345</p>
  </plist>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="reducedList">
  <plist>
    <xsl:copy-of select="ext:node-set($portlist)/plist/p[not(text() = preceding-sibling::p/text())]"/>
  </plist>
</xsl:variable>
```

where `ext` is your extension namespace with `node-set()`, e.g. `xmlns:ext="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"`.

Comment: I added the code, and got an idea what you mean. I also added the xmlns:ext entry, however I do get an error 

XTDE1425: Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt}node-set()

I use Saxon-Pe 9.7.0.15; and must keep compliance to Microsoft Sharepoint 2016 (which to the best of my knowledge is capable only for XSLT 1.0)

Comment: Ah I see the problem (or i guess I see it): while I am testing, I use OxygenXML with Saxon (before moving everything into Sharepoint); however, the function I need might be in MSXML. Right?

Comment: @WalterKuhn For Saxon it's [`xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"`](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/exslt-common/node-set.html).